# I got this error while creating reactive form

Tags: angular, angular10, angular11

Got this error while I fulfill all requirements of reactive forms.

Here are the images of code and error

[app module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaF9p.png)

[users component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVjCA.png)

[component html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9rqB.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwKJt.png)

Comment: Need more clarification, Could you provide your app.module? Also have you imported FormGroup from @angular/forms in user.ts file?

Comment: I have added more images of component module and html

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear from the question but if there is any child module

import formsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in child module

for example if user component is in user module, import forms module and reactive forms module there